# Try/catch handler not behaving consistantly

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, puppeteer, apify

I have the following error handler in a Puppeteer script.  When ran from `node` on my computer, it runs fine.  However, when ran from an Apify Puppeteer-Scraper Actor, it works only if I uncomment `console.log(e)`.  If not, it will always set `notfound` as `true`, regardless of the existence of a `foobar` class element.

```
let notfound = false;
try {
    await page.waitForSelector('.foobar', { timeout: 10 });
} catch(e) {
    // console.log(e);
    console.log('Foobar not found.');
    notfound = true;
}
```

In other languages I would suspect bad memory handling, but I'm not sure it can be the case here ?  What could explain this behaviour ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Does it set `notfound = true` even without logging an error? Else, what is `e`?

Comment: @Jim Since `console.log(e)` is commented, I don't have access to the error message, do I ?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it sets `notfound=true` without logging any other error.  If I uncomment `console.log(e)`, the error is a TimeoutError, but it is only triggered when the `foobar` class element doesn't exist, as expected.

Comment: But it does log `Foobar not found.` before setting `notfound = true`?

Comment: What happens when you remove the line completely, not just commenting it out?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it does log `Foobar not found`.  The same happens when I remove the line, actually I added it for debugging this issue, ultimately I want to skip silently.

Comment: Is the `let notFound = false;` in a higher scope outside the containing `async` function?  If so, you're probably not waiting on the promise returned from the `async` function before examining that variable.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is actually defined and assigned right before the `try`, exactly as in the code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't in the original question (my bad), but `waitForSelector()` had a custom timeout :

```
    await page.waitForSelector('.foobar', { timeout: 10});
```

Now this timeout is set in milliseconds, not in seconds.

Evidently 10 ms is not enough for the `foobar` class object to be rendered by Puppeteer.  Increasing this value solved the issue.